# Reducing SpaceUsedMB in SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

I have a database which is 120GB in size. One of the tables that uses up a large amount of space has thousands of records being created on a daily basis. One of those columns is an `nvarchar(max)`. This column can commonly have 2000 characters of data that only needs to be there for a week.

If I update that column to be blank after a week for those records, it does not seem to reduce the database size. E.g.:

```
UPDATE tblSample 
SET largefieldname = '' 
WHERE DateAdded < DATEADD(D, -7, GETDATE())
```

So if I insert 100mb worth of data into that column, and then blank that column after a week using the above statement, the database still remains 100mb in size.

How can I get the database to reduce in size after such a task? I don't want to delete the entire row, just remove the unnecessary disk usage by that one specific column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider a redesign for the temporary data.
Put the temporary data in its own table and put a key to it in the main table.
When you are done with the data, delete the key value and truncate the table. This will not release the unused space but will make maintenance of it easier. The only way to reclaim usable disk space is to shrink the database or use partitions.

Comment: I like this idea, I will give it a go and see if I can redesign the tables to fit this.

Answer (score 0):

One way to release the space is to copy the table into temp file, truncate the table and reinsert the rows from the temp table.

Try this code:

```
create table dbo.x5 (name varchar(1000),  i1  int IDENTITY(1,1))
set nocount on
-- select the next two rows and run
insert into dbo.x5 values (replicate('abcd',250))
go 10000

exec sp_spaceused 'dbo.x5' --11488 KB
update dbo.x5 set name=''
select * into #a1 from dbo.x5
truncate table dbo.x5
insert into dbo.x5 (name) select name from #a1

exec sp_spaceused 'dbo.x5' -- 136k
```

On a large table with several indexes it may pay to drop the indexes, reinsert the rows, and recreate the indexes. Your results will vary so run the code on your install.

If you have a clustered index on the table doing a rebuild on the index will also free up the space. I don't know if doing a rebuild on a heap (a table without a clustered index) will have the same effect.

Comment: The database is 120GB, and the table I want to do this on is 30GB, with 50 million rows. It will take a long time to move the data across and the website that uses it has 100-1000 people on all the time. It can be done in maintenance but cannot do this every week. Is there any other way?

Comment: Only by creating a clustered index and rebuilding the index. Drop the other indexes, rebuild the clustered index and recreate the other indexes. This approach should be tested to see if it is the most efficient way to go. You should also look into partitioning the table. This will allow you to add, drop parts of the table very, very quickly and even rebuild an individual partition's index. If you want to encourage users to answer questions its nice to vote for an answer.

Answer (score -1):

you can apply a shrink process to the database in this way:

```
USE [YourDatabase]
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'YourDatabase')
GO
```

this is the command provided by SQL Server in order to return that space to the OS but also keep in mind that this is not recomended as this process create fragmentation over your indexes and also will impact CPU cost during the process, please take a look at the following reading http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/why-you-should-not-shrink-your-data-files/

Comment: Dont use shrinkfile. This is very, very bad advice. This will take a long time, and hose the response time of your database after you do it. Shrinkfile should be used once every couple of years in an emergency. Please see for example these two writers (there are many, many more): http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SHRINKFILE/71414/  and http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/01/19/sql-server-shrinking-database-is-bad-increases-fragmentation-reduces-performance/

Comment: I do agree with your comments that's why I do make some emphasis that this process is not recommended it's up to the user in proceed or not and also add a blog from Paul Randal about http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/why-you-should-not-shrink-your-data-files/

Comment: So why recommend it? Its like telling someone to lose weight by bleeding themselves.